# Host WCF IIS could not find assembly .dll

Tags: .net, wcf, iis-7

Im trying to host a WCF service on IIS.I created a virtual directory,set application pool to v.4.0 framework,set the pysichal path to the application path.

And when try to run the service i get follow error:
"Could not load file or assembly 'ingdnp.dll' or one of its dependencies."

Does anyone what is that DLL?I couldnt find anything on google.

UPDATE:

I need to register DLL in GAC (Global Assembly Cache).
THK All

Answer (score 2):

it's very easy to solve your problem. Just *delete* the `ingdnp.dll` from your *bin folder*, project or references.

Comment: Very usefull. I did it! I have a very smart friend that told me to do this, but I didn't believe him. But I believe in you. Thanks a lot "Solving Your problem". Little Delicious... this is for you.

Answer (score 1):

Is it in your application's bin directory?  Sometimes these errors occur because you have a native or mixed-mode DLL dependency that is compiled in 32bit mode and your application pool is 64 bits (or vice-versa).  The DLL is actually present but cannot be loaded.

Another reason that I see a lot is that the DLL that is failing to load is dependent on a version of the C runtime library (MSVCRT) that is not present on the system.  To figure this out, you can load up the offending DLL in  [Dependency Walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/)  and see what if it reports a missing dependency (and if so, what version).

Comment: I dont understand your question...What is in my bin directory?

Comment: You should have a "bin" subdirectory underneath your application's root directory (where IIS is pointing) which contains the compiled service and its dependencies.

Comment: Sorry, I'm suggesting "ingdnp.dll" might have been put there (in "bin") by the compiler because it is a dependency of your application.

Comment: yes,that DLL is in my Bin directory,but the error says that could not find it

Comment: The error you pasted says that it could not load it, not that it could not FIND it.  That could be due to the reason in my answer.  Another possibility is that ingdpn.dll needs a particular version of the C Runtime library (msvcrt) to exist on the machine, and it can't find that and thus fails to load.

Comment: Which ones are listed?  Generally, you can ignore the warning about IESHIMS.DLL

Comment: Well, that's your problem. ingfips.dll is most likely part of some API produced by Ingrian which your code is importing.  Find it and make sure it gets copied to your bin directory, or remove the code that depends on it.

Comment: I find a solution,by registering the 'ingdnp.dll' in the GAC.